# Can yolov5 bounding box convert to segmentation?

Tags: python, polygon, bounding-box, yolov5

I trained yolov5 with bbox and it also has weights.
But now I need segmentation, can I change the bbox to segmentation>?

so , i found changing segmentation to bbox, but not the opposite

My bbox data was created in RoboFlow, but it is difficult to recreate it with segmentation.